# Multiple entry visa for Singapore

Tags: visas, singapore

I am an Indian passport holder living in Japan. I am travelling to India through Singapore and returning back to Japan via the same. Since the arrival and departure are at different terminals, I came to know that visa is essential. Is it possible to get a multiple entry visa from here? What should I do for that?

Comment: What airlines are you flying with, and do you have a single ticket?  You don't necessarily need a visa just to change terminals.

Comment: I'm flying with China Eastern till Singapore and to India with Indigo. I've 2 tickets, 1 is till Singapore and another is to India from Singapore.

Comment: Do you have checked luggage?

Comment: Yes, I do have luggage.

Answer (score 1):

Singapore's Changi Airport has a total of 3 terminals, numbered Terminals 1, 2 and 3.  (There was previously also a "Budget terminal", however this was closed down several years ago)

All terminals are connected air-side, both by walkways and by "Sky Train", and thus there is no need to exit immigration to move between terminals.

The only exception to this may be if you are travelling with luggage, and on an airline(s) that will not allow the luggage to be checked through to your final destination.  In this case you will need to exit immigration to collect and re-check your luggage.

Comment: The OP's second flight is with an LCC (IndiGo), so they will need to go through immigration to collect and recheck their luggage.

Comment: So, will I be in need of Visa?

Comment: If you have checked-in luggage, then **yes**, you will need a visa. Full stop.